# Setting Win10 Accent Color via Group Policy

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to set a default color and accent color for all users via GPO and am having issues.  Whenever I set Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific background and accent color I always end up with black as the color.  Any ideas?

This is on Win10x64 v1607 Education.

Comment: What are the exact settings you used in that GP?

Comment: Have you tried to manually push the group policy update?

Comment: I have tried tried manually refreshing the group policy.

Comment: Currently the values in the GPO are 006400 for Start background color and 004000 for Accent color.

Comment: Based on the `Help:` detail of that policy, it says... "The color values are specified in hex as #RGB."... You say you have these set as `006400` and `004000`. So my question and or suggestions to try if you've not otherwise, in addition to the `gpupdate /force` command from elevated command prompt as others suggested, would be to try with `#006400` and `#004000` add the `#` pound symbol to those values as the the starting suffix.

Comment: BruBrake - What was your solution?

Comment: @Spittin'IT   Adding the # in the value of the GPO solved the issue, but just for new profiles on a PC and only on Education versions of Windows, which is fine as the PCs in question are lab units that get reloaded often.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good deal, you should add that as an answer and then tag me back so I can up vote it!! It may be useful information for others looking for similar solutions,